# when should I save quest progress to server?

Tags: java, android, ios, libgdx, server

I am making a game for Android/iOS. I have recently got daily quest to work nicely, the only problem is I can't figure out when I should save quest progress.

I don't want to make a servercall everytime you do something in the game that could effect quest progress.

Say for example your quest is "win 3 games", I was thinking of just putting quest progress in preferences until you completed the quest, but that can lead to a bunch of unwanted behaviour if you exit the game when your progress is for example 2/3.

Is there a smart way to go about this or do I just have to make a servercall and save directly into db every time you do something that can effect a daily quest?

As far as I know there is no way to do it when the user exits the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a smart way to go about this or do I just have to make a
>   servercall and save directly into db every time you do something that
>   can effect a daily quest?

iQue, make a server call every time and validate the data they are sending you (did they really achieve what they're claiming?), users can root the device or modify the game client, so this is the only correct way to do it.

> As far as I know there is no way to do it when the user exits the app?

If you want to do anything when the app is exited on Libgdx, there is again only one correct (in the spirit of Libgdx) way to do it and it's not mentioned in the other answers, as you can write this cross-platform without delving into Android/iOS specifics: override the dispose method of your main game class (ApplicationListener).

Comment: Thanks for all the answers boys, I think Ill go with server call then :) Ill just have to try and make it as painless as possible for the user experience

Answer (score 1):

I would save it as soon as something changes. Your server will probably be able to handle this and you don't need to mess around with platform specific stuff.

If you really want to avoid this for some reason you would have to look at the platform specific ways to execute code just before the app exits. On iOS this seems to be `applicationDidEnterBackground()` on Android you can use `onDestroy()` .

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a smart way to go about this or do I just have to make a
>   servercall and save directly into db every time you do something that
>   can effect a daily quest?

I'd choose server call.

> As far as I know there is no way to do it when the user exits the app?

There are onPause, onDestroy methods in android. You can use SharedPreferences and when user exit the app, delete that data.

But whatever you do, never trust the client data. Always try to validate data in server.